# Is it possible to Store 0 as the first digit in integer variable

Tags: c++

I want to assign a value of `097` to an integer variable. I don't want it to get implicitly converted to `97`. Is this possible?

```
int i=097;
cout<<i;
```

`OUTPUT` as `097` : `Possible?`

I need to put the value in the link list in reverse order. So if the user is inputting `097` I need to parse it digit wise and store in link list as `7->9->0`. Its not the exact program but its something I am trying to achieve. There can be other ways like using arrays and all. But I was just wondering if I can parse `0` via using `int` variable.

Comment: `097` is not a valid integer literal (9 is not a valid octal digit). What value do you want to assign to `i`?

Comment: Then you need to read that number into a string. As I said, as far as C++ is concerned, `097` isn't even a number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Integers are stored in binary, not as individual digits. Therefore, all information not related to the value of the integer is not stored.

Perhaps you would like to store your value in a string instead?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't make sense to say that the value of an `int` is `97` or `097`. What you want is a way to format your output. To do that, can [`std::setwidth` and `std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill).

`cout << setwidth(3) << setfill('0') << i;`

Comment: @Vulcan it's not clear to me what the general case is

Comment: I got your point. Actually I needed to work on reverse of the number entered by the user. I have editted the main query. Kindly check once. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user1292432 As others have commented and answered, there is no way of doing this with an `int`. Try taking the input as a [`string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). You can call [`reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) on it and perform other operations as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Not with an integer variable. To achieve this, you could either use a string or some other method of tracking how many leading zeros the number should have.

Incidentally, a leading zero in a C++ integer literal turns it into an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal. This makes your program malformed since it's trying to use a non-octal digit `9` in an octal literal.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, try using a string to display the value.Use `to_string` function to convert the integer to a string and just insert a leading zero at the beginning.

```
int i = 97;
std::string s = std::to_string(i);
s.insert(0,"0");
```

EDIT: You can then store the digits into the list by iterating through the string.